# Grails: @BindUsing on a class being ignored and @BindUsing vs ValueConverter

Tags: grails, data-binding, valueconverter

I need to do some custom data binding and I tried to use the @BindUsing annotation on a class (http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/grails/databinding/BindUsing.html), however, it's being ignored.  I am under the assumption that since the annotation is used on the class that would mean that every time a data binding happens and that class is involved, the BindingHelper class would be used, but it's never actually called.  Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Here's the class definition where UserBinding is a class that implements the BindingHelper interface:

```
@BindUsing(UserBinding)
class User extends SomeOtherClass
{
  ...
```

Also am I correct in understanding that basically creating a ValueConverter and using @BindUsing on a class accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

`BindUsing` on a class is not used often and there seems to be a [bug reported](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Domain-Level-BindUsing-td4655608.html) around that already. [From the link] The problem could be that there are multiple request parameters with the same name it might be using the helper only for the first one.
Using a property level `@BindUsing` annotation should be simpler to implement and is less likely to fail (even when there are multiple entries in the params map with the same name).